# How to destructor to get property message

Tags: javascript

I like to have this complex object to be destructured so I can have the property "message".

How can I achieve this?

`complex object to destructured`

```
{"data":[{"success":false,"message":"Not Found!"}]}
```

Comment: Does that array always contain exactly one item? If not, what else can it look like? (And if it does, then why is it an array in the first place?)

Comment: Can you show us your attempt, please? Do you know how simpler objects are destructured?

Comment: The array contain exactly the same one item, The only thing that would change are the object values based on Joi-validation

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { data: [{ message},]} = {"data":[{"success":false,"message":"Not Found!"}]}

console.log(message)
```

Comment: However, if the first member is not there it will result in an error.

Comment: True. But if there is no first element the array will be empty. Which defeats the purpose of destructuring to get "message".

Comment: Thanks @urchmaney, There will be always an object in the array even if there is no error. e.g : {"data":[{"success:  true, "message": " "}]}, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {"data":[{"success":false,"message":"Not Found!"}]};

const {data: [{message}]} = obj;

console.log(message); // Not Found!
```